# Invalid CSS on rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I just got this error while I was running bundle exec rake test

> invalid CSS after "body ": expected selector or at-rule, was "{"
>
> app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:10
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in
>   `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2839044906013100383_53889300'
>   test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:6:in`block in
>   '

I then looked at app/asset/stylesheets/custom.css.sccss l

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

line number 10 is `padding-top: 60px;`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check any missing semicolons in above css

Comment: @TamilSelvan ya that was it, Thanks !